# Is there a way to increase the performance of PHP's tidy function?

Tags: php, html, performance, tidy

I wanted to ask you if you know a way to increase the performance of PHP's tidy function?

Using it like this at the moment:

```
while($ds = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($ds['description']);
    $html =  tidy_parse_string($tidy, array('show-body-only'=>true, 'indent'=>true));
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_*** SET description = '".mysql_real_escape_string($html)."' WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ds2['id_artikel'])."'";
    sql4query($sql);

    $allerr = $allerr + tidy_error_count($tidy);
    $allwar = $allwar + tidy_warning_count($tidy);
    $msg .= $ds['id'].":\n".$tidy->errorBuffer."\n\n\n";
}
```

But it's just too slow, with more than 10 million data sets.

Comment: why are you calling `tidy_parse_string` twice?

Comment: Rather than batch tidy ALL the records (many of which may never be viewed), you can just run the tidy function when someone attempts to view/edit a particular record.

Comment: @FuzzyTree I implemented it like shown i the documentation. But you are right, I shouldn't exec it 2 times.

Comment: Just recompile it with the `--dontsuck` flag. .. Sorry, couldn't resist. ;P Seriously though, not sure what kind of magic answer you expect. It's probably already doing its job as fast as it can.

Comment: @DigitalChris the problem is, that I need to clean these records once. The new ones will be cleaned by inserting into the database.

Comment: @deceze I am sorry, but I hoped there are some guys out there who already worked some time with the tidy function, who got some nice hints how to squeeze out the last drop of performance.

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do except grin and bear it.  Parsing HTML is a pretty expensive task, even moreso if it's broken in some way.

Comment: "Squeezing out the last drop of performance" is typically only possible for code that you write yourself. Not for prepackaged libraries. I'm sure nobody is leaving a `sleep(100)` call in there on purpose... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other comments already said, there’s probably no reasonable way to make the tidy extension doing its work any faster.

> the problem is, that I need to clean these records once. The new ones will be cleaned by inserting into the database.

So how many “old” records are we talking about  – thousands, tenthousands, …?

If you can not get it done “all in one go” (cronjob, no execution time limit, run during a maintenance phase “over night”) – then the alternative is to do each record individually, once – when it is “needed” for the first time.

You add a column to your table, `still_needs_to_be_cleaned` or something, and set that to true/1 for all existing records. On inserting a new record you simply set it to false/0.

Now, when a record is requested (by visitor of the site or whatever), you *check* whether the flag `still_needs_to_be_cleaned` is still set to true – if so, you let tidy run on that single record, and update it in the database afterwards – setting `still_needs_to_be_cleaned` to false while doing so.

If the record has `still_needs_to_be_cleaned` set to false already – then no tidy-action and no update is needed, you can proceed with outputting that record straight away.

Yes, this will mean a small delay for the first user requesting a certain record – but most likely, it will hardly be noticeable, if at all.

---

And if you want, you can even check from time to time, how many records still have the `still_needs_to_be_cleaned` flag set to true. If there’s none left, you could remove that extra logic again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as mentioned, I am talking about more than 10 million records. Problem is the memory load of the server which just crashes our test system. I am "cleaning" the database in steps of 5.000 records in a cronjob but its just too slow. So I think I have to do it like you mentioned and I hoped to avoid.